# HTML5's FileReader Upload Takes All of Browser's Memory

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, filereader

I've developed an upload app which uses HTML5's FileReader, jQuery and PHP. The browser memory increases every time a chunk is sent, until it reaches the "out of memory" error. Am I doing something wrong? Here's my script:

```
function startUpload(file){
    var freader = new FileReader();
    var chunkN = 1;
    var chunkSize = 1048576;
    var fileSize = file.size;
    var offset = 0;
    var totalChunks = parseInt(fileSize / chunkSize);

    if (fileSize % chunkSize != 0) {
        totalChunks++;
    }

    var sendChunk = function(e){
        if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
            var result = e.target.result;
            var fd = new FormData();

            fd.append('file', result);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajaxr/upload.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: fd,
                timeout: 10000,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (r) {
                    if (chunkN < totalChunks) {
                        chunkN++;
                        setTimeout(function() { createChunk(); }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            )};
        }
    }

    function createChunk() {
        offset = (chunkN - 1) * chunkSize;
        var blob = file.slice(offset, chunkSize + offset);

        freader.onload = sendChunk;
        freader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }

    createChunk();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you upload the blobs directly instead of converting them to data urls?

Comment: Is this possible? I've read somewhere you have to turn blobs into URLs or Binary strings first.

Comment: Depends on(like everything else in web development) browser comparability.